# Duplicate symbols but cant access the classes

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am consuming two related libraries (.framework format) in Xcode. One of the libraries (lib1) depends on the other (lib2). The app directly references classes from both lib1 and lib2 so both .frameworks need to be included in the project.

When I add both libraries to the project I get the duplicate symbols error. But when I remove the lib2 I cannot access the classes I need.

I think that lib1 is not exposing the classes that I need (not that it should). But how can I access the classes from lib2 and avoid the duplicates error?

Note: I am aware this is a strange configuration for the libraries. This is an edge case where the project is actually I diagnostic/test tool and not the typical usage of the libraries.

Comment: Keep the common thing in one library and please remove the common thing from another library by removing the common thing from Copy Bundle Resources under Build Phases category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add only the headers in your project, since the sources are included in the library and are not needed.

Make sure the headers you include are the same version as the sources included in the library, or you may have runtime crashes.

Comment: Ok, that worked, THANKS! But, it's awkward. Can't I do something with header search?

Comment: You could search for the headers inside the .framework and add the path to the "Headers search path" in the Xcode project. I'm not sure if all headers are available there, probably not.